# Does there exist a notation for the number of terms in a sum?

Tags: summation, notation

If $S$ were a set comprised of $n$ elements we would say that the cardinality of $S$ is $n$ and denote said cardinality as $|S|=n$. Does there exist any notation alike the mentioned one for the  number of terms in a sum?

Comment: The cardinality of the set of indices/ indexation set?

Comment: I doubt it. Note that when you write a sum, you don't really write the sum, but its result. For example, $5+7$ is exactly the same as $12$, but $5+7$ has two addends and $12$ has only one. Perhaps you need some mathematical metalanguage to do that. I don't know if there is a such thing.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @MJD $R = {a, b, c} => |R| = 3$. $S = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4=>$ "The sum $S$ has four terms. Does their exist a notation alike |R| that denotes the number of terms in a sum? I hope this example clarifies the question. Nevertheless, I believe that ajotatxe's answer explains why it is unlikely that such a notation would exist for sums. After all $S = 3 = 2 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 1$, so the number of terms in the sum $S$ could be said to equal 3, 2 or 1 (and an infinite range of other additions that yield the value 3).

Comment: Well, sort of.  $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ has... $n$ terms.  And $\sum_{k=b}^na_k$ has $n-b+1$ terms and $\sum_{i\in K}a_i$ has $|K|$ terms.  It's not notation but terminology and convention that if you have a sum, the summands can, and implicitely are, indexed and the indexes belong to an indexing set so the notation would be $|K|$ where $K$ is the set of indexes.  The unstated assumption is the notation $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ is actually that the indexing set is $\{1,2,...\}=\mathbb N_{n}$ and the sum is actually $\sum_{k\in\mathbb N_{n}}a_k$.  And the cardinality is $|\mathbb N_{n}| = n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematical operations deal with properties of mathematical objects. But the number of terms in a sum is a property of the way the sum is written; that is, it is a property of the *expression* of the sum.  In contrast, the number of elements in a set is a property of the set itself, and is independent of the way it is written.  For example:

$$\{n\in \Bbb Z \mid n^2\lt 4\}\\
\{-1, 0, 1\}\\
\Bbb Z \cap \left(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right)\\
$$

are three different ways to write the same set, and regardless of how it is written, the set has exactly 3 elements.

A similar issue arises sometimes when one wants to discuss the numerator of a fraction.  One has to be careful to speak only of the numerator of a *fraction*, which makes sense, and not of the numerator of rational number that might be represented by a fraction, which does not. The rational number $1.25$, for example, could be represented as $\frac54$ or as $\frac{500}{400}$, which have different numerators.    One can of course work around the issue.  All I claim is that the issue exists.

Here you want to discuss the number of terms in a sum, which is a certain type of mathematical *expression*.  This can be done, but only if you are treating the expression itself as a sort of mathematical object.  This kind of thing is done, but usually only in specialized contexts, and I am not aware of any universal standard notation for it.

One context in which we often discuss the number of terms in a sum is the context of polynomials.  A polynomial is a special sort of mathematical expression, one which comes up often enough that the expression itself is considered to be a kind of mathematical object. One often talks about the number of terms in a polynomial.  The representation issue I mentioned does come up.  For example, is the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ the same as the polynomial $x^2 + 0x + 1$?  What about $0x^3 + x^2 + 0x + 1$? And how many terms are there?  We always agree that these are the same polynomial, and that it has exactly *three* terms.  The jargon for this is that that polynomial has [*degree 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial), which is often written as something like $\deg P = 2$. In some contexts one might want to talk about the number of *nonzero* terms, so that a polynomial like $x^{53}+x+1$ has three nonzero terms although its degree is 53. I'm not aware of any special notation for this.

In a more specialized context, dealing with more general expressions, here's the kind of thing we *might* do:

1. We might decide to understand an “expression” as a [rooted tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Rooted_tree) whose leaves are numbers and whose interior nodes are labeled with operations, chosen from some suitable set that includes `+`, `×`, `÷`, and so forth.  For example, the expression $“2×(9+(5-2))”$ might be identified with this tree:

[image: Tree with four leaves and 3 interior nodes]

2. An expression can then be defined to be a “sum” if each of its interior nodes is labeled with either `+` or `-`.  So the tree of the previous illustration is not a sum, but its right-side subtree is a sum.
3. In this case, the number of terms in the sum can be defined to be the number of leaves in the tree.  The right-side subtree here has three leaves, so it is a sum of three terms.
4. Now we can define a notation to represent the number of terms in a sum:  If $E$ is a sum expression, then $\operatorname{terms}(E)$ is the number of terms in  $E$.  Or we could use $|E|$ or $|E|_+$ or whatever.  mathematical notation is often fluid and ad hoc.

One could then extend the definition of “expression” to include expressions of the form $\sum_{n\in S} f(n)$ and the like, and the definition of “number of terms” to say that this expression has $|S|$ terms, or $1$, or whatever is desired.

Maybe this was more than you wanted to know, but I hope if so it was at least interesting.